# Subquery returned more than 1 value. in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I query data in my application, I get the following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is use as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Below is my stored procedure. anyone help me please?

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SP_RC_DS_2]

@CustomerID varchar(10),
@ExfacDateFrom Datetime,
@ExfacDateTo DateTime

SELECT
         SOD_SOLineNbr as Line_No
        ,IMA_LeadTimeCode as Manu_Pur
        ,IMA_Classification as Category
        ,case when IMA_ItemName is null then SOI_MiscLineDescription else IMA_ItemName end as ItemName
        --,SOI_MiscLineDescription as MiscLine
        ,IAD_AliasName as AliasName
        --,SOD_UserDef1 as PrivateRemark
        ,PrivateRemark =
            (Case CUS_CustomerID
            When 'C1175' Then   isnull(convert(nvarchar(200),SOM_SpecialInst),'')  + ' / ' + isnull(SOD_UserDef1,'')
            When 'C1209' Then   isnull(convert(nvarchar(200),SOM_SpecialInst),'')  + ' / ' + isnull(SOD_UserDef1,'')
            Else SOD_UserDef1
            End)
        ,SOD_UserDef2 as RemarkLine--
        ,CUS_CustomerID as CustomerID
        ,CSA_Name as CustomerName
        ,SOM_Destination as Destination
        ,SOM_ContainerSize as ContainerSize
        ,CSA_RecordID as CSA_RecordID
        ,SOM_SalesOrderID as SalesOrderID
        ,SOM_CustomerPOID as CustomerPO
        ,SOD_RequiredDate as ExFacDate
        ,SOM_DefaultDockDate as ETD
        ,SOM_ETA as ETA
        ,SOD_PromiseDate as PromiseDate
        ,SOD_RequiredQty as Qty
        ,SOI_SalesConvUnitMeasure as UnitMeasure
        ,SOD_UnitPrice as UnitPrice
        ,isnull(IMA_Weight,0) as NetWeight
        ,isnull(IMA_GrossWeight,0)as GrossWeight
        ,(Case When IMA_ProdFam is null then 'Others' else IMA_ProdFam end) as ProdFamilyItem
        ,(Case When IMA_ProdFam is null then 'Others' else (Select PFM_PGI From PFM Where PFM_ProdFam = IMA_ProdFam) end) as ProdFamInvGroup
        ,UnitVol =
                (Case When(Select Count(*) From RC_Special_UnitVol Where SU_CSA_RecordID =CSA_RecordID and SU_IMA_ItemID =IMA_ItemID) =1
                      Then (Select SU_CubicVolume From RC_Special_UnitVol Where SU_CSA_RecordID =CSA_RecordID and SU_IMA_ItemID =IMA_ItemID) 
                      Else isnull(IMA_CubicVolume,0) End)
        ,IMA_CubicVolUnitMeasure as VolUnitMeasure
        ,isnull((SOD_RequiredQty * 
                (Case When(Select distinct Count(*) From RC_Special_UnitVol Where SU_CSA_RecordID =CSA_RecordID and SU_IMA_ItemID =IMA_ItemID) =1
                      Then (Select SU_CubicVolume From RC_Special_UnitVol Where SU_CSA_RecordID =CSA_RecordID and SU_IMA_ItemID =IMA_ItemID) 
                      Else isnull(IMA_CubicVolume,0) End)),0) as TotalUnitVol
        ,SOM_DefaultVATCodeID as Vat
        ,SOM_SpecialInst as RemarkPO
        ,SOM_Buyer as OrderNumber
        ,isnull(EMP_MidName,'-')+' '+ isnull(EMP_LastName,'-')+' ('+ isnull(EMP_FirstName,'-')+')' as LastUpdateBy
        ,SOI_LineNbrTypeCode as LineTypeCode
        ,isnull(IMA_Kit,'') as Kit
        ,IMA_ItemID as ItemID--> Add
        ,day(SOM_DefaultRequiredDate) as [Day]
        ,month(SOM_DefaultRequiredDate) as [Month]
        ,year(SOM_DefaultRequiredDate) as [Year]

Into #OPS

FROM    SalesOrder
        Inner Join SalesOrderLine on SOM_RecordID = SOI_SOM_RecordID
        left Join ITEM On IMA_RecordID = SOI_IMA_RecordID
        left join ItemAliasDetail on IAD_RecordID = SOI_IAD_ID 
        inner Join SalesOrderDelivery On SOD_SOI_RecordID = SOI_RecordID
        inner Join EMP On SOM_EMP_RecordID = EMP_RecordID
        inner Join Customer On CUS_RecordId = SOM_CUS_RecordId
        inner join CustomerShipTo on CSA_RecordID =  SOM_DefaultCSA_RecordID

Where SOD_RequiredDate Between dbo.Fn_Rc_DateWithTime(@ExfacDateFrom,0) and dbo.Fn_Rc_DateWithTime(@ExfacDateTo,1)

And CUS_CustomerID = @CustomerID
And SOI_LineNbrTypeCode = 'Item'

order by  SOM_SalesOrderID,SOD_SOLineNbr
--Select * From #OPS
Select 
CustomerID,
CustomerName,
ItemID,
AliasName,
PartName = (Select  IMA_ItemName From Item Where IMA_ItemID = ItemID ), 
PrivateRemark,
Qty,
ExFacDate,
SalesOrderID,
CustomerPO,
OrderNumber,
where IMA_ItemID = ItemID)
UserDef1 = (Select WH_LOC from VW_ItemID_WH_Loc where IMA_ItemID = ItemID)

Into #TempFinish
From #OPS
order by ExFacDate

Select * From #TempFinish
Drop table #OPS
Drop table #TempFinish
```

Comment: You have two queries and both has sub-queries in it.. Check which query is throwing error first..

Comment: Execute this procedure in SSMS and find the line number which give you the error.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shows when you use Sub query and =,>,< etc operators, and the sub query returning more than one record.

Try changing this:

```
PartName = (Select  IMA_ItemName From Item Where IMA_ItemID = ItemID )
```

to this:

```
PartName = (Select Top 1  IMA_ItemName From Item Where IMA_ItemID = ItemID
```

This is applicable to all the places in your query where such same scenario is there

Comment: Yup true. My bad.. corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Now it will not throw error.. but not sure whether it logically correct.. My guess would be there is missing predicate in `Where` clause or atleast you need the `Order` column when you use `TOP`..